# How to compare two collections that vary by properties using Fluent Assertion?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have public class `RuleInfo` which is created from internal class `Rule`.

```
private static RuleInfo CreateRuleInfo(Rule r)
{
    return new RuleInfo
    {
        RuleCode = r.RuleId,
        DisplayName = r.RuleCode,
        Description = r.Description,
        LegacyRuleCode = null
    };
}
```

They vary in their properties names so `ShouldBeEquivalentTo()` or `ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo()` don't work.

Right now I'm comparing them manually/explicitly:

```
foreach (var x in Enumerable.Zip(infs, rules, (i, r) => new { Info = i, Rule = r }))
{
    x.Info.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(
        new
        {
            RuleCode = x.Rule.RuleId,
            DisplayName = x.Rule.RuleCode,
            Description = x.Rule.Description,
            LegacyRuleCode = (string)null
        });
}
```

Is there a better, more compact, less explicit, more readable way?

Comment: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/535

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there currently isn't a way to specify a mapping between properties when comparing different types. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/535) about it.

Here's an example on another way to compare two collections.
Be aware that I'm assuming that `==` performs value equality. 
So if all your properties are `int` and `string` you are home safe.

```
ruleInfos.Should().Equal(rules, (ruleInfo, rule) =>
    ruleInfo.RuleCode == rule.RuleId
     && ruleInfo.DisplayName == rule.RuleCode
    && ruleInfo.Description == rule.Description
);
```

For e.g. a reference type with no overload of `==` you would need to handle null values gracefully with e.g.

```
(PropertyA == PropertyB) || (PropertyA?.Equals(PropertyB) == true
```

Answer (score 7):

One option is adding custom equivalency step to global options configuration:

```
class DifferentObjectsEquivalencyStep<T1, T2> : IEquivalencyStep {
    private readonly Func<T1, T2> _converter;

    public DifferentObjectsEquivalencyStep(Func<T1, T2> converter) {
        _converter = converter;
    }

    public bool CanHandle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config) {
        return context.Subject is T1 && context.Expectation is T2 || context.Subject is T2 && context.Expectation is T1;
    }

    public bool Handle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator parent, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config) {            
        var first = context.Subject is T1 ? (T1) context.Subject : (T1) context.Expectation;
        var second = context.Subject is T2 ? (T2) context.Subject : (T2) context.Expectation;
        second.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(_converter(first));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere before you do all comparisions:

```
AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing(c => c.Using(
            new DifferentObjectsEquivalencyStep<Rule, RuleInfo>(CreateRuleInfo)));
```

After that, regular `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` (and `ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo`) will work:

```
rule.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(info);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I leaned more about FA API from it. Just found Jonas' answer is quite shorter :)