# FluentAssertions - Should().BeEquivalentTo() when properties are of different type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

How to compare objects that have a property with the same name but different type?

```
public class A
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public static B Map(A a){
    return new B { Id = a.Id.ToString() };
}
```

*Version 1:*

```
void Main()
{
    A a = new A { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
    B b = Map(a);

    b.Should().BeEquivalentTo(a);
}
```

This produces the following error:

> AssertionFailedException: Expected member Id to be {ff73e7c7-21f0-4f45-85fa-f26cd1ecafd0}, but found "{ff73e7c7-21f0-4f45-85fa-f26cd1ecafd0}".

The documentation suggests that custom property assertion rules could be possible using the [Equivalence Comparison Behavior](http://fluentassertions.com/documentation.html#equivalency-comparison-behavior)

*Version 2:*

```
void Main()
{
    A a = new A { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
    B b = Map(a);

    b.Should().BeEquivalentTo(a, 
        options => options
            .Using<Guid>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().Be(ctx.Expectation))
            .WhenTypeIs<Guid>());
}
```

but it produces run-time exception if the properties are not of the same type.

> AssertionFailedException: Expected member Id from subject to be a System.Guid, but found a System.String.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two approaches to compare objects with identically named members of different type.

The first way is to specify equivalency between members named `Id`

```
A expected = new A { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
B actual = Map(expected);

actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected,
    options => options
    .Using<object>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().Be(ctx.Expectation.ToString()))
    .When(info => info.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Id")));
```

The second approach uses the `DifferentObjectsEquivalencyStep` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47947052/1087627 and your own `Map` function.
It then converts instances of `A` into `B`, which are now easy to compare.

```
AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing(c => 
    c.Using(new DifferentObjectsEquivalencyStep<A, B>(Map)));

A expected = new A { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
B actual = Map(expected);

actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/535) about it.

Comment: DifferentObjectsEquivalencyStep should be added to fluentassertions, as extension methods!

Comment: @MichalCiechan Feel free to open an issue about on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues).

I'm currently fiddling with another approach where you'll be able to write `.Using<string, Guid>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().Be(ctx.Expectation.ToString())).When(info => info.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Id")))`. 
That should be less fragile and more expressive.